# Reformulating the tube lemma to say that the projection is closed

Tags: general-topology

I need to prove, using the Tube Lemma, that the projection $\pi_1 X\times Y\to X$ is closed if $Y$ is compact. I've found a solution to this below:

[image]

but it doesn't prove anything, it's just a comment.

My understand of the tube lemma is that, if we have a slice $\{x\}\times Y$ inside an open $N$ of $X\times Y$, and $Y$ is compact, then there will exist an open set $W\times Y$ that is contained in $N$, when $W$ is a neighborgood of $x$.

Now I need to prove that the projection is closed. I tried to imagine a closed set in $X\times Y$ as a bunch of points, as an example. Then, I imagined the slice $\{x\}\times Y$ not intersecting those points and contained in an open $N$. By the tube lemma, there will exist a tube $W\times Y$ containing the slice and contained in $N$. So every point outside my 'bunch of points' is an interior point because it's contained in an open that does not intersect the 'bunch of points'?

As I remember, a projection is closed if it takes a closed set to another closed set. Where is my closed set being mapped to something in the proof above? Also, what if my closed subset of $X\times Y$ is not a bunch of points, but a rectangle? Could somebody help me visualize this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $C$ be a closed subset of $X\times Y$, and let $H=\pi_1[C]$; you want to show that $H$ is closed in $X$. Let $x\in X\setminus H$. Then $\{x\}\times Y$ is disjoint from $C$, so $\{x\}\times Y$ is a subset of the open set $(X\times Y)\setminus C$. By the tube lemma there is an open nbhd $W$ of $x$ such that $W\times Y\subseteq(X\times Y)\setminus C$, i.e., such that $(W\times Y)\cap C=\varnothing$. This implies that $W\cap H=\varnothing$, i.e., that $W$ is an open nbhd of $x$ disjoint from $H$. Since $x$ was an arbitrary point in $X\setminus H$, $X\setminus H$ is open, and $H$ is closed.

There is no need to visualize the closed set $C$. At most it may be helpful to have a visual schematic something like the one below.

[image]

The closed set to which $C$ is mapped by the projection is $\pi_1[C]$, shown in red in the sketch.